# When change $IFS in bash on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, bash

I met a problem when I change the value of $IFS in bash on Mac OS X. For example, I have a main directory `/XXX/XXX/XXX`, and two sub-directories `subdir1` and `subdir2`. If I run the shell script

```
maindir=/XXX/XXX/XXX;
subdirs=$(find $maindir -type d -maxdepth 1);
echo $subdirs
```

Normally I get the results like this

```
/XXX/XXX/XXX/subdir1 /XXX/XXX/XXX/subdir2
```

These two subdirectories are separated by `Blankspace`. The problem is, when I change once the `$IFS` value like this:

```
OLDIFS=$IFS; 
IFS=$'\n';
IFS=OLDIFS;
```

After that, if we check again the value of `$subdirs`

```
echo $subdirs
```

The results become

```
/XXX/XXX/XXX/subdir1
/XXX/XXX/XXX/subdir2
```

It seems that bash automatically changes `Blankspace`  to `\n`. This really bothers me. Is there a solution to change `\n` back to `Blankspace`? My system is Mac OS X version 10.7.5.

Comment: What's with the `;` line terminators?

Answer (score 7):

You didn't properly reset `IFS` (or properly set `OLDIFS` in the first place):

```
OLDIFS="$IFS"
IFS=$'\n'
...
IFS="$OLDIFS"
```

(This fails to restore `IFS` to an unset state if it was unset prior to saving its "value", but that's probably not worth going into here.)

Answer (score 1):

it's often helpful, when you need to change `IFS`, to do it in a subshell. Then, when the subshell ends, the modified value of IFS disappears. An example

```
set -- a b c
echo "main: $*"             # using default value of IFS
( IFS=:; echo "sub:  $*" )  # modify IFS in a subshell
echo "main: $*"             # previous IFS value restored
```

outputs

```
main: a b c
sub:  a:b:c
main: a b c
```